# How to clear ajax response data?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to parse JSON with jQuery.

Here's my code

```
var urlto ="some url";

function loadNews(){

    $.ajax({
    url: urlto,
    dataType: 'json',
    type:'get',
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {

        var art = data;

        var source = art.news;

        var i;

        for (var i = 0; i < source.length; i++) {
         var x = art.news[i];

         var titles = x.title;
         if(titles.length > 73){
             titles = titles.substring(0, 69)+"...";
         }

         var descriptionvr = x.description;
         if(descriptionvr.length > 66){
             descriptionvr = descriptionvr.substring(0, 64)+"...";
         }

         document.getElementById('result').innerHTML += '<style>.new_container{width: 100%; border:2px solid gray; border-bottom-left-radius: 30px; border-top-left-radius: 30px;}.new_container img{height: 270px; width: 430px; display:inline; border-bottom-left-radius: 30px; border-top-left-radius: 30px;}.title{float: right; width: 53%; padding-top: 10px; color: #50597B; font-weight: 600; font-size: 40px; font-family: sans-serif;;}.desciptions{color: #50597B; float: right; width: 53%; font-weight: 400; font-size: 19px; font-family: sans-serif; margin-top: -11%;}.attribute{color: #50597B; float: right; font-weight: 400; font-size: 18px; font-family: sans-serif; margin-top: -2.5%; padding-right: 7px;}.wrapper{padding-bottom: 30px;}</style><div class="wrapper"><div class="new_container""><img src="'+x.image+'"><div class="title">'+titles+'</div><div class="desciptions">'+descriptionvr+'</div><div class="attribute">'+x.author+' - '+x.published+'</div></div></div>';

        }
    }
});
}
```

I also have button which call function called **changeURL**

Here is the function

```
function changeURL(){
urlto = "some another url";
loadNews();
}
```

This function basically **change the URL and call Ajax function again** but, the issue is when i change the URL and call the Ajax function again it **show the old JSON data from old URL plus new data JSON from new URL. I mean it mix-up old and new JSON data together** but, **I only want to show new JSON data.**

Is there any way to solve this.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

First of all, never put CSS like this. You should put all CSS code either in a separate file ("styles.css", for example), or in the "head" of your HTML page. The separate file is better.

To reset the "result", try:

```
var urlto ="some url";

function loadNews(){

    $.ajax({
    url: urlto,
    dataType: 'json',
    type:'get',
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {

        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = ""

        var art = data;

        var source = art.news;

        var i;

        for (var i = 0; i < source.length; i++) {
         var x = art.news[i];

         var titles = x.title;
         if(titles.length > 73){
             titles = titles.substring(0, 69)+"...";
         }

         var descriptionvr = x.description;
         if(descriptionvr.length > 66){
             descriptionvr = descriptionvr.substring(0, 64)+"...";
         }

         document.getElementById('result').innerHTML += '<style>.new_container{width: 100%; border:2px solid gray; border-bottom-left-radius: 30px; border-top-left-radius: 30px;}.new_container img{height: 270px; width: 430px; display:inline; border-bottom-left-radius: 30px; border-top-left-radius: 30px;}.title{float: right; width: 53%; padding-top: 10px; color: #50597B; font-weight: 600; font-size: 40px; font-family: sans-serif;;}.desciptions{color: #50597B; float: right; width: 53%; font-weight: 400; font-size: 19px; font-family: sans-serif; margin-top: -11%;}.attribute{color: #50597B; float: right; font-weight: 400; font-size: 18px; font-family: sans-serif; margin-top: -2.5%; padding-right: 7px;}.wrapper{padding-bottom: 30px;}</style><div class="wrapper"><div class="new_container""><img src="'+x.image+'"><div class="title">'+titles+'</div><div class="desciptions">'+descriptionvr+'</div><div class="attribute">'+x.author+' - '+x.published+'</div></div></div>';

        }
    }
});
}
```

Comment: I have already tried it no help as i have to show multiple items with JSON data and using this show all single item from data of json

Comment: Then I think you'll have to show us more code. What are you writing instead of "do something"?

Comment: I gave you a solution I think

Comment: No i will focus on CSS part but issue is still there, i want that when button click all data from old JSON URL get delete and only New data from New JSON URL show that all. @djcaesar9114

Comment: You confirm me that with the code I wrote the "result" doesn't reset?

Comment: The line `document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = ""` resets the element with "result" as ID. You may have several elements with this ID, maybe. Show us your HTML code.